# one-to-many with Collection<Integer>

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have a table "seance" in DB ('id' is a PK):

```
CREATE TABLE seance(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    seance_id int,
    number int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

seance

```
id, seance_id, number
1, 111222, 1951
2, 111222, 1951
3, 111222, 1951
4, 333222, 1415
5, 333222, 1415
6, 333222, 1415
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seance")
public class Seance {

    public Seance() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "seance_id")
    private Integer seanceId;

    @Column(name = "number")
    @ElementCollection// it is wrong cause require TWO tables
    //what I should write here or modify?
    private Set<Integer> number = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public Seance(Integer seanceId, Set<Integer> number) {
        this.seanceId = seanceId;
        this.number = number;
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

As a result I want to have an instance of Seance class:

> Integer seanceId: 111222;
>
> Set number:  1951, 1951, 1951;

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your entity like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seance")
public class Seance {

    public Seance() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "seance_id")
    private Integer seanceId;

@ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
        name="NUMBER",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
  )
    private Set<Integer> number = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public Sessions(Integer seanceId, Set<Integer> number) {
        this.seanceId = seanceId;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Integer getSeanceId() {
        return seanceId;
    }

    public void setSeanceId(Integer seanceId) {
        this.seanceId = seanceId;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getNumber() {
        return number;`enter code here`
    }

    public void setNumber(Set<Integer> number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

doing like this, you will have two tables and number is going to have a table, without being and entity. Moreover, your conception is event bad because you have redundance that is something to avoid when deeling with DataBases. 
 you can also follow this link
 https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Comment: do you know how to load data from ONE table?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Actually If you have an intance of seance loaded from the DB, then you can access it list of number like this  listSeances.getNumber();

Comment: I have an Exception. My object "Seance" didn't load cause I have ONE table, but hibernate want to load from two tables.

Comment: yes you actually need two tables for that, the second table has a column number and another column that references  the first table(seance)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is meant to handle several non-standard relationship mappings,  the `ElementCollection` can be used to define a one-to-many relationship and the `ElementCollection` values are always stored in a separate table.

Comment: do you know what should I do to achieve my goal - retrieve data from ONE table. I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: @SergeyChepurnov sure, absolutely, and from the docs, ElementCollection values are always stored in a separate table, this is the answer but not the solution, so you should do it in the "right way", maybe custom your own type(`UserType`) to store your numbers separated by "," in one column.